# How to take the text content(JSON) from the element content in XML content in Java

Tags: xml, json

I have String which is an XML element. I have made this element to pass the JSON as payload element. I am able to send the request. How to take the JSON content from the XML element(String) excluding the CDATA ?

**I am sending the request XML element as:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<saveProject>
<data>
<![CDATA[{"createProject":{"project": {"createDate": "2014-03-20","createdBy": "PARAMETER","endDate": "2014-05-23","owner": {"address":{"city":"Bangalore","country":"India","state":"Karnataka","street":"Address Line 1,Address Line 2","zip":"560001"}"contactNo":"9823984234","emailID":"ravi@mphasis.com","name":"Mphsais"}"phase":"Design","projDesc":"Test Desc","projName":"Ravi-Test","startDate":"2014-03-18"}}}]]>]]&gt;
<![CDATA[</data></saveProject>]]>
```

**I want the output as:**

`{"createProject":{"project": {"createDate": "2014-03-20","createdBy": "PARAMETER","endDate": "2014-05-23","owner": {"address":{"city":"Bangalore","country":"India","state":"Karnataka","street":"Address Line 1,Address Line 2","zip":"560001"}"contactNo":"9823984234","emailID":"ravi@mphasis.com","name":"Mphsais"}"phase":"Design","projDesc":"Test Desc","projName":"Ravi-Test","startDate":"2014-03-18"}}}`

Can anyone please help with some code to achieve this.

Comment: You've missed a few commas. It's not a solution, but I guess it matters.

Comment: Thanks. Its will matter